# Update a table using CTE and NEWID()

Tags: sql-server, random, common-table-expression

I want try update a table using random values from the same table, but the original table don´t have a identity to follow or any other number column...

```
WITH cteTable1 AS (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS n,
    ENDE_NO_Address
FROM TableX
)
UPDATE TableX SET ENDE_NO_Address = (
   SELECT ENDE_NO_Address 
   FROM cteTable1
   WHERE cteTable1.n = This is the problem...
```

tnks for the help

Comment: and !?!?!!?! What's your question?? Does it a) not work? b) give you an error (if so: **WHAT** error?), or c) not give random values??

Comment: So the table has no primary key you say?

Comment: @gbn: so it's *not really* a table then ...... :-)

Comment: i need to use the original information from the table to random the updates.

Comment: the original table dont have a PK.

Comment: is a table with address, i just need to update in a random order

Comment: the script don´t work because I dont have some to folow in the where,,,  i have some like `create table test (date datetime, address)` and a lot of address,,, i need to put the address in random but not change the date and not lose address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @T table(Col1 varchar(10))

insert into @T values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

;with cte as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(order by newid()) as rn1,
         row_number() over(order by Col1) as rn2
  from @T
)

update C1 set
  Col1 = C2.Col1
from cte as C1
  inner join cte as C2
    on C1.rn1 = C2.rn2
```

**Edit:**

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS n1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 1)) AS n2,
    ENDE_NO_Address
FROM TableX
)
update C1 set
  ENDE_NO_Address = C2.ENDE_NO_Address
from cte as C1
  inner join cte as C2
    on C1.n1 = C2.n2
```

Comment: this last one put all the columns with null, but i change the select 1 to ENDE_NO_ADDRESS and work fine...

TNKS a lot

Comment: @Ricardo - Strange not in my tests. Does the first one using a table variable work for you? Unless there is a typo somewhere they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing...

```
UPDATE TableX
SET ENDE_NO_Address = (
   SELECT TOP 1 ENDE_NO_Address FROM TableX ORDER BY NEWID()
   )
```

Comment: The result will be a bit different compared to what I have posted. Perhaps this is more correct, using a random value. My version don't reuse addresses. So I guess my version actually scrambles the data instead of "using a random value" as the OP stated.