# How to speed up update query in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
update orders
set tname = (select top 1 t.task
                from task t
                where prod_typ='2' and sorder_nbr = t.ORDER_NBR
                order by t.strt_dt desc) 
where Prod_type='2'

update orders
set tname=  (select top 1 t.task
                from task t
                where  prod_typ='1' and sorder_nbr=t.ORDER_NBR
                order by t.strt_dt desc)
where Prod_type='1'
```

I am trying to update the `tname` column of `orders` table by the latest task from the `task` table

And the condition is `prod_typ` of `orders` table is 1 and `sorder_nbr` of `orders` table and order_nbr of `task` table are equal

My first update statement works well where the rows are 900k and for the second update rows are 400k for second update statement it takes more than one hour to run and at last I cancelled the query

Comment: Since correlated subqueries are the slowest method to do anything, I would suggest you never use them again. Use a join in your update.

Comment: If the sub queries are slow then how my first update statement works fast i can't understand why my second update statement is too slow which is same as first statement, in my scenario i cannot use join.

Comment: @user2838918: can you post here the actual execution plan (as XML if possible)?!

Comment: Why you can't use a join?

Comment: You can do this update in one statement. And yes execution plan would help.

Comment: is it Prod_type or Prod_typ?

Comment: maybe your statistics is out of whack?

Comment: @ all i cant post my execution plan since it contains confidential data @ sam yi it is Prod_tupe

Answer (score 3):

1) You query and my query:

```
update orders
set tname = (select top 1 t.task
                from task t
                where prod_type='2' and order_nbr = t.ORDER_NBR
                order by t.strt_dt desc) 
where Prod_type='2';
go

update o
set tname = (select top 1 t.task
                from task t
                where prod_type='2' and o.order_nbr = t.ORDER_NBR
                order by t.strt_dt desc) 
from dbo.orders o
where Prod_type='2';
go
```

The actual execution plans:
[image]

As you can see, if default collation for current DB is CI (case insensitive) then following predicate `order_nbr=t.ORDER_NBR` force SQL Server to compare the values of `t.ORDER_NBR` with  the values `order_nbr` column from the same table `task t`. Look at first execution plan which corresponds to first query.

To solve *just* this problem, I've used another alias
`dbo.orders o` and I've reqrite the predicate thus `o.order_nbr = t.ORDER_NBR`. You may see this also within second execution plan.

*Depending on how many tasks are for every order_num & prod_type you could test S#1 if there are many tasks or S#2 if there is a small amount of tasks per order_num & prod_type.* Again, you need to test with your data to see which solution is better.

2) Solution #1:

```
UPDATE  o
SET     tname = 
        COALESCE(
            (SELECT  TOP(1) t.task
            FROM    dbo.task t
            WHERE   t.prod_type=o.Prod_type 
            AND     o.order_nbr = t.ORDER_NBR
            ORDER BY t.strt_dt DESC), tname
        ) 
FROM    dbo.orders o
WHERE   o.Prod_type IN ('1', '2');
```

3) Solution #2:

```
UPDATE  o
SET     tname = lt.task
FROM    dbo.orders o 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT  src.order_nbr, src.prod_type, src.task
    FROM (
        SELECT  t.ORDER_NBR, t.prod_type, t.task,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.ORDER_NBR, t.prod_type ORDER BY t.strt_dt DESC) RowNum
        FROM    dbo.task t
    ) src 
    WHERE src.RowNum = 1
) lt -- last task
ON o.order_nbr = lt.ORDER_NBR AND o.prod_type = lt.prod_type
WHERE   o.Prod_type IN ('1', '2');
```

If you have questions then feel free to ask.

4) An index on `dbo.task(order_nbr, prod_type, strt_dt) include (task)` should help both solutions.

5) Also you should publish the actual execution plans.

Comment: actualy in my db both column names are different

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean: Are you sure it's not a bug in showing info about table scan operator in query plan? I mean, if this would be true, than that condition is true no matter what are the values in task.order_nbr and the UPDATE will be conduct to strange results (like updating order.tname with values from other order_nbr). Anyway I found your remark very interesting, and it will nice if you provide an official reference on this.

Comment: Yes. There is no bug. This happens because there is a `order_nbr` in both tables and the local column has priority if no alias is used. So `(SELECT ... FROM task t WHERE ... order_nbr = t.ORDER_NBR ...)` <=> `(SELECT ... FROM task t WHERE ... t.order_nbr = t.ORDER_NBR ...)` if collation is case insensitive. Reference: ANSI SQL.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I used cte and update the table it works in 3 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. This will update prod_type of 1 and 2 at the same time.

```
UPDATE orders
SET tname = t1.task
FROM orders o
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT order_nbr, prod_type, t.task, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY order_nbr, prod_type ORDER BY strt_dt DESC) rownumber
    FROM task t
    WHERE o.prod_type = t.prod_type
        AND o.order_nbr = t.order_nbr) t1
WHERE t1.rownumber = 1
    AND o.prod_type in (1,2)
```

Comment: Nice solution. Additionally, I think an index on task.order_nbr (with prod_type as included column?!) would help. Also it might help to have a clustered index on task.strt_dt column.

Answer (score 1):

If the data size is large than i suggest you to use variables for updating the table, or Using CTE to update

[Update a table using CTE and NEWID()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705932/update-a-table-using-cte-and-newid)

[Updating record using CTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978967/updating-record-using-cte)

I hope this will help

with tname (t.task) as 
(select top 1 t.task
                from task t
                where prod_typ='2' and order_nbr = t.ORDER_NBR
                order by t.strt_dt desc )
insert into Orders(t.task)

Answer (score -1):

Using a CTE query will speed up this, because the subquery is need not be created for every row, it is pre-prepared. Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/759f41/3)

```
   ;with cteTaskNames as
   (
     select top 1 t.task
     from task t
     where  prod_type='2' and order_nbr=t.ORDER_NBR
     order by t.strt_dt desc
   )
   update orders
   set tname = (select task from cteTaskNames)
   where Prod_type='2'
   go
```

Also, 
    1) Is "prod_type" an integer field or a string field?
    2) If you add group by in the cte, you can do an inner join on orders and cte query to run all updates at once instead of doing each query.

Comment: prod_type is a string field

Comment: I have verified the above in the sqlfiddle and it is working fine. Does this answer your question user2838918??

Comment: @ConsultYarla if i use this i get a single task i need to get a task for each order nbr in my order table there is one order nbr and in the task table there are different task for that order nbr i want to map the latest task in to that order nbr from that task table

Comment: @BogdanSahlean am the one who rise the query i did not down vote any one

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: I found it normal to downvote a solution that is not working. Btw, did you follow the fiddle link and Mani's last comment? I will be happy to upvote in case the response is updated.

Comment: @ConsultYarla I just used update table using common table expression I modified your query and used it in 3 minutes I updated the table thanks for your idea